# Can Clonezilla restore an image to a different partition number than originally?

Tags: linux, windows, images, restore, clonezilla

Assume the following situation:

UEFI-based dualboot system consisting of Windows and Linux.

Partitioning:

- Partition 1: FAT32, EFI-Boot-Partition
- Partition 2: EXT4, Linux Root /
- Partition 3: EXT4, Linux Home /home
- Partition 4: NTFS, Windows
- Partition 5: NTFS, Microsoft reserved partition

**The question now is:**

If I create a backup-image from the Windows-partition (partition no. 4) via Clonezilla, can I restore this image **to partition no. 2** on a empty drive and reconfigure the Windows bootloader to target to partition no. 2 then?

In initial state, the Windows bootloader would point to the partition no. 4 where Windows is not existent anymore.

Or is it only possible to restore images to the initial partition number where they were created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, perfectly possible - when restoring the advanced options let you choose which partition you want to restore into, if you're restoring just a partition image.

However, if you've got a whole drive image this won't work.

Comment: So it is possible to restore the previous Windows partition 4 to the new partition 2? But how does the Windows EFI-bootloader detect that Windows is now on partition 2 instead of the initial partition 4?

Comment: You'd have to reconfigure it - that i'm unsure how to do.